# Can anyone help me identify this old computer part?

Tags: mainframe

I purchased two identical computer parts at an estate sale that seemed unusual. I was told that perhaps it was a component from an old IBM mainframe.

I was able to date them between late 50's and early 60's from the logo that was in use at the time. However, I have no idea what purpose they served.

Can anyone help?

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: That looks like a modular screwdriver.

Comment: It does appear to be a key of some sort with the intent that both ends be utilized as jacks or inserts.

Comment: Why upload a screenshot of the picture if you already have the picture?

Answer (score 41):

According to [this page](https://raggio5.smugmug.com/History/Computer/i-XFf292P/A) it's a wire punch tool for a 1940 IBM 402 computer programming board.

From that page (screenshot of the page is below):

> 1940 IBM 402 Computer Programming Board A tidbit fact: Temporary,
> orange tipped wires were easier to insert and remove. They were used a
> lot during the testing and design programming phase. Permanent wires
> the ones with no orange ends were used after a programmer was sure
> that the program was working right. The permanent wires were inserted
> with the red wire punch tool and also were remove from the back with
> the same tool.

[image]

(Note: on that page click the white 'i' circle icon for Photo Details to see the quoted text above)

Comment: You can get one on eBay also (for now): https://www.ebay.com/itm/313983535095

Comment: From the days the program needed to be hardwired into the computer.

Comment: Well, you certainly brought about closure to that question. Thanks a million!

Comment: The IBM 402 dates from the late 1940's, so it's not a computer. It's a tabulating machine. IBM's first mass-market computer was in the mid-50s.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe The line between tabulating machines and computers is a rather blurry one. Machines like ENIAC are without doubt considered computers, despite being  patch board programmed.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I don't think it is actually a computer part.
Looks more like a handle/key to open a computer case.
Case is maybe the wrong word... They were more the size of large cupboard back in the day.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tommy.  Let me know if you come up with something more specific.

Comment: @user1746209 Squillman got it right. I knew I had seen the bloody thing before when I was in university about 35 years ago. There was a whole collection of similar tools lying around there. Some were handles/keys, but some others were wire-punches.